# Publishing and Marketing

Tags: publishing, copyright, marketing

How hard is it to find a publisher for first time author?

What are the risks of our story getting stolen and what are the ways to protect it?

What are various ways of marketing so that the book reaches various parts of the world?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Writing SE! We try to ask and answer questions as less generic as possible here. I would suggest you to focus your question more, because it seems you are asking three different things here. Also, make sure to search in the website for similar questions that might already help you out. Welcome, and good writing!

Comment: Have placed this on hold until it can be edited.